# MySQL does not support select INTO?

Tags: mysql, sql

My following SQL query has errors from MySQL workbench, and error is table "new_table" not recognized. Does it mean MySQL does not support select into statement?

```
SELECT student_id 
into new_table
FROM students;
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: @IgnazioC:- No it does not. Please go through the link. OP has asked about inserting the data into the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [MySQL does not support the SELECT ... INTO ... syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html).

You have to use it like this:

```
Insert into new_table
Select * FROM students;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
CREATE TABLE new_table as SELECT student_id FROM students;
```

If the table already exists:

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM students;
```

[This thread](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html) has some details on the syntax differences.

Comment: select into does not supported by MySQL?

Comment: Syntax is just slighty different.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
insert into new_table
  Select * FROM students;
```

Comment: Thanks @Bernd, select into does not supported by MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You may Try This way:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (student_id)
SELECT student_id FROM students
```

My Two Table table structure in sql with data:

```
/*Table structure for table `new_table` */

CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*Data for the table `new_table` */
insert  into `new_table`(`id`,`student_id`,`name`) values (1,401,NULL),(2,402,NULL);

/*Table structure for table `students` */
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*Data for the table `students` */
insert  into `students`(`id`,`student_id`,`name`) values (1,401,'matin'),(2,402,'rahman');
```